# Is the function $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^4+y^2}$ a $C^1$-function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the function 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^4+y^2}.
$$
with $f(0,0) = 0$. 
Is this a $C^1$-function?

Firstly we compute: 
\begin{align*}
& D_1f(x,y) = \frac{y^3(x^4+y^2)-xy^3(4x^3)}{(x^4+y^2)^2} = \frac{y^3(y^2-3x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}, \\
& D_2f(x,y) = \frac{3xy^2(x^4+y^2)-xy^3(2y)}{(x^4+y^2)^2} = \frac{xy^2(3x^4+y^2)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}, 
\end{align*}
and $D_1f(0,0)= D_2f(0,0) = 0$. The function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with $f'(\vec{0}) = [0,0]$, since we can verify that: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\|\vec{x}\|} & = \frac{|x||y|^3}{x^4+y^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{|x||y|}{\frac{x^4}{y^2} + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{|x||y|}{\left( \frac{x^2}{y} \right)^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{\|\vec{x}\|} \\
& \leq |x||y| \cdot \frac{1}{\|\vec{x}\|} \leq \|\vec{x}\|^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\|\vec{x}\|} = \|\vec{x}\| \to 0 \textrm{ als } \vec{x} \to \vec{0}. 
\end{align*}

In order to determine if it is $C^1$, we need to determine whether the partial derivatives are continuous on the entire domain. I am trying to determine this for the point $(0,0)$, and so I need to determine
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3(y^2-3x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}, 
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2(3x^4+y^2)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}. 
$$
I'm stuck in this step, I don't know how to compute these limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$\left\vert \frac{y^3(y^2-3x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2} \right\vert \le \vert y \vert^3\frac{(y^2+3x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2} \le 3 \vert y \vert^3 \frac{(y^2+x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}= 3 \frac{\vert y \vert^3}{x^4+y^2} \le 3\vert y \vert$$ hence
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3(y^2-3x^4)}{(x^4+y^2)^2} = 0.$$

Using a similar argument you also get

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2(3x^4+y^2)}{(x^4+y^2)^2}=0.$$

This proves that the partial derivatives are continuous at the origin and that $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Just checking my understanding: for the first inequality we have for the numerator: 
$|y^3(y^2-3x^4)| \leq |y^3(3y^2-3x^4)| = |3y^3(y^2-x^4)| \leq  |3y^3(y^2+x^4)| = 3|y^3(y^2+x^4)|$. Is it also possible to do this: $|y^3(y^2-3x^4)| \leq |y^3(y^2+x^4)|$ to avoid the $3$? Since $-3x^4 \leq x^4$. I'm not sure if this is allowed.

Comment: You don't always have $|y^3(y^2-3x^4)| \leq |y^3(y^2+x^4)|$. Take $y=1$ and $x=2$ for a counterexample.

Comment: What about the very similar $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3 (y^4 - x^2)}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik This is not even bounded around $(0,0)$ as you can see taking $x=0$ and $y \to 0$.